# Laravel page loads over 1s in production (while blazing fast locally on my dev macbook)

Tags: performance, laravel

I've shipped my Laravel based platform to a production server but with little to no users online page loads are still above 1 second, around 1,5s. There's little to no data in the database. I've optimized with the several php artisan cache commands. I've full control over the server, as it's a VPS from a large Dutch cloud service provider.

The server is running CentOS 7.

When inspecting load times using `top` on the server, I see PHP (`php-fpm81`) has around 35% CPU usage while handling a page load. Other than that I see high CPU usage for a process `datasq`, around 150%. However, I don't feel this is related as other user's website on the same VPS runs perfectly fine (e.g. a clients Wordpress site performs good)

I'm not sure where to look for answers. Any suggestions on how to improve performance? When shipping to a broader public current performance won't retain users.

Comment: Can you show the full path of the `datasq` process? Can you give further information on the setup, what software is installed there?

Comment: What you're looking for is basically profiling. See e.g. [this Q&A on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133/simplest-way-to-profile-a-php-script)